# Using a TinyMCE Language Pack (Malayalam) is not working fine

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I am facing a problem in loading the TinyMCE 3.5.8 for malayalam language. I have did the following steps. 
1. Downloaded the TinyMCE.3.5.8
2. Downloaded the language pack(malayalam) for TinyMCE 3.x

and done the following steps.

Edit the html file tinymce/examples/simple.html

```
tinyMCE.init({

     language : "ml", // change language here

     mode : "textareas",

     theme : "simple"   

});
```

Uploaded the following:

/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/langs/

/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/langs/

/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins//langs/

Issue: When I run the  tinymce/examples/simple.html it is not loading the textarea, when I change the language to en it textarea is working fine. Can anybody say how can I fix this issue?

Or please suggest any other rich text editors to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above, you say that you've uploaded `...themes/advanced/langs`, but the simple.html loads the simple theme.  If you want to use the simple theme, upload `...themes/simple/langs` as well.  Alternatively, if you only plan on using the advanced theme, set `theme` to advanced and see if it works.

If that doesn't fix your issue: If your browser has a network monitor, use that to check for 404 responses on the simple.html test page.  It'll tell you which file it's not finding as expected.

Comment: I have uploaded the ...themes/simple/langs as well, now it is loading the text editor and its giving english language itself. The requested lang is not all working.

Comment: The Malayalam translation isn't complete. (And I'm not sure the test text would be replaced)  If you switch to the advanced theme and click the 'add an image' button, or use the HTML button, you should see text for specific, but not all, controls are replaced.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed, the tooltips for the format controls in the simple theme are replaced, so no need to switch to advanced to see it.  Just mouse-over, say, the text bolding control.  The content of the text area will remain in English and gibberish latin.  The language packs will not translate content, only UI components.

Comment: Wow! I did the same, changed the theme to advanced now it is showing the controls in malayalam language. But the content is not yet converted to malayalam language.

Comment: This is correct. The language packs can only replace predefined strings, like those in UI controls.  They cannot perform content translation.  I'm not aware of any plugins that will translate content entered into TinyMCE.  You should be able to type Malayalam content into the text area without issue though.